# Importing training data from local directory in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to import some training data from my local directory into a python program. Currently I am following a tutorial and in this tutorial the data is imported with the help of the following code:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
```

But my problem is that my data is present in my local directory so I cannot use this approach. Your help will be highly appreciated. My local directory contains multiple files and I have to import them all through one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of scikit. First install it and then use the below code for reading the files from local directory

```
 import sklearn.datasets
 data = sklearn.datasets.load_files(path, shuffle='False')
```

Answer (score 1):

create a folder `data` in your local directory where you put all your data, then you can refer to it using `./data`. Then, to access the local `data` folder, the following should work:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./data/", one_hot = True)
```

You can also get the current directory programmatically, and then construct the path to the data directory as follows

```
import os 

# get the current directory 
current_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# create the path to the data directory within the current directory
data_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "data")
```

Then, edit your code as follows:

```
import os 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# get the current directory 
current_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# create the path to the data directory within the current directory
data_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "data")

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(data_directory, one_hot = True)
```

**EDIT: based on your comment, you are asking about how to load your own data in tensorflow:**

As recommended in the documentation, if you are new to TF it's better to start with this tutorial:

- [tf.contrib.learn Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn)

Comment: "from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data"
Actually this line will go to "tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist" and will import input_data from there. Then this line "mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./data/", one_hot = True)" will download the data in "data" folder. You can try it.
I don't want to do this, i have some training data other than data present "tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist" on this link. And my training data is in my local directory.